# Remote debugging(c++) with visual studio code

Tags: c++, ssh, visual-studio-code, gdb, remote-debugging

I searched for how to open and edit file located on remote server via local visual studio code(IDE). But I also wanted to do remote debugging, which means I will control the gdb command(via GUI)from the IDE instead of terminal.

I checked [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_remote-debugging), but it is for node.js. 
Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

I use GDB extension for Visual Studio to debug my applications on remote linux machine.

Check out : [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MarcGoodner-MSFT.VisualCforIoTDevelopment)

For reference See: [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/11/18/announcing-the-vs-gdb-debugger-extension/)

In case you are developing apps on linux you may want to see the Linux workload from visual studio installer.

Comment: Bit late to the party but ...That's a different IDE ;-).